# Drag and drop using uft for sapguiTree object

Tags: hp-uft, uft14

How can we drag a node in sapguitree and drop it in sapgui element?
I have tried device replay method but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop is not allowed in SAP application when scripting is enabled. You can try recording using analog mode and playing back the track if the position of your node and element is constant. We tried this for one of our scenarios and works fine every time.